# Importing Python modules on Linux from an NTFS share

Tags: python, windows, linux

My problem is a difference in how Python searches for modules on Windows/Linux.

I have a directory `foo` on a Windows 7 machine (NTFS), which I mount in a Ubuntu 10.04 virtual guest running on the same machine (via VirtualBox' guest additions). Inside `foo`, there is a file `OS.py` (note the upper case) with the following content:

```
bar = 1
```

Here's the output of a Python (2.5.4) session on the host (Win 7) inside `foo`:

```
>>> f = open('os.py') # Note the lower case
>>> f.readlines()
['bar = 1\n']
>>> f.close()
>>> import os
>>> dir(os)
(content of the Python standard os package)
```

And here's the output on the guest (Ubuntu), running Python 2.6.5 in `foo`:

```
>>> f = open('os.py') # Note the lower case
>>> f.readlines()
['bar = 1\n']
>>> f.close()
>>> import os
>>> dir(os)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'bar']
```

So on both platforms, Python loads the same file `foo/OS.py` when using `open('os.py')`, which is fine, since NTFS is case-insensitive. What I don't understand is the different behaviour regarding `import`. I would have expected that `foo/OS.py` is imported on both platforms, or at least that the behaviour is the same.

Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

Note: `''` is the first entry in `sys.path` on both platforms.

Comment: Sounds more like a VirtualBox issue than a Python issue...

Comment: @ignacio: What makes you think so? In theory the Python on the guest shouldn't even notice that it is running in a virtual OS, at least not for operations such as searching for files and reading them.

Comment: The problem is not the fact that it's running in a VM, but rather the file sharing. For some reason the VFS thinks that "OS.py" is the same file as "os.py".

Comment: @ignacio: But isn't that correct? NTFS should be case-insensitive, so there should be no difference between `OS.py` and `os.py`. In the code above, the calls to `open` behave that way. Even if NTFS was case-sensitive, there is still the question of why `open` and `import` behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Linux or NTFS, the behaviour is exactly the same in a pure Windows environment with any Windows file system NTFS or FAT: Windows regards filenames as case insensitive, but Python regards module names as case sensitive.

All that is happening here is that when Python searches for a module it does its own case-sensitive search so it never sees the lower case filename: it isn't blindly trying to open the file 'OS.py' in every folder on the Python path, it is searching each folder for files named 'OS' plus any of a number of possible extensions, that search on Windows might return files named 'os' but they are immediately filtered out and ignored.

If I remember correctly the exact behaviour has varied over time: very old versions of Python would ignore the case when importing modules on Windows, then it became a warning and now it simply ignores them.

For more information see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0235/ (but I don't know if it is entirely up to date).

Comment: That's what I suspected. Do you happen to know where I can find further information? The [Python docs for modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) isn't very detailed regarding this topic.

Comment: I added in a link to the PEP, but it's pretty old. The 'proposed new semantics' seem to have been implemented in Python 2.1 beta 1: http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.1.2/NEWS.txt

Answer (score 0):

If You want to find import your selfmade OS.py in linux enviroment, you can add path to foo/ dir in PYTHONPATH variable. 
Something like this: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/PathToFoo. also you can run python interpreter like this: env PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/PathToFoo python

Comment: I know that I can change the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, but that solves only a particular case where I know the locations of modules with problematic names. I'm more interested in finding out why this happens and what to do in order to avoid it in a general case.